# jQuery - Toggle two switches but not both?

Tags: jquery, toggle, switch-statement

I have a tricky little problem. In this example I have created there are two switches and two coloured squares: http://jsfiddle.net/amQCN/

I am trying to ensure that only one switch can be *off* at one time, so there is always at least one coloured square showing - or *both*.

I have also been trying to figure out; if switch (1) is *on*, and you click switch (2), it toggles to make (2) *on* and (1) *off* - as above, you would then not be able to turn switch (2) *off* but you could turn switch (1) back *on* so they are both *on*.

I hope that makes sense! - can anyone suggest a method to get this to work?

```
<ul id="switches">
<li><a id="switch1" href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a id="switch2" href="#">2</a></li></ul>
<ul id="squares">
<li id="square1"></li>
<li id="square2"></li></ul> 


$(function() { 

$('#switch1').toggle(function() {
    $('#square1').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#switch1').addClass("off");
}, function(){
    $('#square1').css("visibility", "visible"); 
    $('#switch1').removeClass("off");  
});

$('#switch2').toggle(function() {
    $('#square2').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#switch2').addClass("off");
}, function(){
    $('#square2').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#switch2').removeClass("off");      
}); });
```

CSS

```
#switch1, #switch2 {background:grey; border:1px solid; border-radius:4px; color:white; cursor:pointer; display:block; float:left; margin:0 3px 5px 0; padding:6px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; width:50px;}
#switch1.off, #switch2.off {background:white; color:#ccc;}
ul#squares li {float:left; margin:0 3px; padding:6px;}
#square1 {background:green; height:20px; width:25px;}
#square2 {background:orange; height:20px; width:25px;}
```

Comment: Although live example links are a great *adjunct* to a question, always post the relevant code actually into the question itself. People shouldn't have to follow links to help you, and external links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. (Remember that StackOverflow is meant to be resource for people with a similar problem in the future, not just your problem right now. Hence being sure the whole thing is still there.)

Comment: Good point, I will update the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() { 

    $('#switch1').click(function() {
        if ($('#square1').is(":visible")) {
            if ($('#square2').is(":visible")) {
                $('#square1').hide();
                $('#switch1').addClass("off");
            }
        } else {
            $('#square1').show(); 
            $('#switch1').removeClass("off");  
        }
    });

    $('#switch2').click(function() {
        if ($('#square2').is(":visible")) {
            if ($('#square1').is(":visible")) {
                $('#square2').hide();
                $('#switch2').addClass("off");
            } 
        } else {
            $('#square2').show();
            $('#switch2').removeClass("off");      
        }
    });

});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/qzjy6/

Or display the other if you hide the last: http://jsfiddle.net/wvREX/

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I meant. Cant believe how quickly everyone responded! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

how do you want it to work?

If switch 2 is off do you want to disable switch 1 being switched off or do you want switch 1 to go off and switch 2 come on automatically?

if you want to disable a switch then you need to wrap the 2 lines that hide it inside an if statement checking the visibility of the other square (or if the other switch hasClass('off')).

if you want to switch the other on then do that check after the 2 lines that hide the square..

Comment: Hi, cheers for your answer. Basically, I am trying to avoid both squares being 'off', whilst also having them toggle if the other one is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

To attack problems like this, always use this approach: Start from a place where you know what the state of the two switches should be. For example you have a place to click to turn button #1 "on". Use this pseudo-code:

```
onclick="turnOn(button1)"

function turnOn(b) {
    setButton(button1, b === button1);
    setButton(button2, b === button2);
}

function setButton(b, on) {
    ... set button to "on" if on === true else to "off"
}
```

That is: Always set the state for all buttons. Don't try to be smart and to create a "patch" (i.e. a minimal set of changes to reach the desired target state). This is brittle and will eventually fail·